# Plotting numerous layers (bar graph) using ggplot and R

Tags: r, excel, graph, ggplot2

I am trying to recreate a bar graph that I created in Excel using data that lists inventory and sales throughout the year. Here is my graph in Excel:

Note: Average sales rate is total sales / total inventory for the 13 months in the bar graph.
[image]

I am doing this through R and the ggplot package. I am quite new at this but this was what I managed so far:

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(reshape2)

COdata <- read.csv("C:/.../CenterOne.csv")

# Grab related data
# VIN refers to a unique inventory identifier for the item
# First Launch Date is what I use to count my inventory for the month
# Sale Date is what I use to count my sales for the month

DFtest <- COdata[, c("VIN", "First.Launch.Date", "Sale.Date")]
```

Here is a snapshot of what the data looks like:

```
> head(DFtest)
                VIN First.Launch.Date       Sale.Date
1 4T1BF1FK4CU048373   22/04/2015 0:00                
2 2T3KF4DVXCW108677   16/03/2015 0:00                
3 4T1BF1FKXCU035935   19/03/2015 0:00 20/03/2015 0:00
4 JTDKN3DU3B1465796   16/04/2015 0:00                
5 2T3YK4DV8CW015050                                  
6 4T1BF1FK5CU599556   30/04/2015 0:00
```

I convert the dates to a proper format removing the hours/seconds and breaking them up into monthly intervals:

```
DFtest$First.Launch.Date <- as.Date(DFtest$First.Launch.Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
DFtest$Sale.Date <- as.Date(DFtest$Sale.Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
DFtest$month.listings <- as.Date(cut(DFtest$First.Launch.Date, breaks = "month"))
DFtest$month.sales <- as.Date(cut(DFtest$Sale.Date, breaks = "month"))

> head(DFtest)
                VIN First.Launch.Date  Sale.Date month.listings month.sales
1 4T1BF1FK4CU048373        2015-04-22       <NA>     2015-04-01        <NA>
2 2T3KF4DVXCW108677        2015-03-16       <NA>     2015-03-01        <NA>
3 4T1BF1FKXCU035935        2015-03-19 2015-03-20     2015-03-01  2015-03-01
4 JTDKN3DU3B1465796        2015-04-16       <NA>     2015-04-01        <NA>
5 2T3YK4DV8CW015050              <NA>       <NA>           <NA>        <NA>
6 4T1BF1FK5CU599556        2015-04-30       <NA>     2015-04-01        <NA>
```

## Avg line graph - my attempt at creating one

```
DF_Listings = data.frame(table(format(DFtest$month.listings)))
DF_Sales = data.frame(table(format(DFtest$month.sales)))
DF_Merge <- merge(DF_Listings, DF_Sales, by = "Var1", all = TRUE)

> head(DF_Listings)
        Var1 Freq
1 2014-12-01   77
2 2015-01-01  886
3 2015-02-01  930
4 2015-03-01 1167
5 2015-04-01 1105
6 2015-05-01 1279

DF_Merge$Avg <- DF_Merge$Freq.y / DF_Merge$Freq.x

> head(DF_Merge)
        Var1 Freq.x Freq.y       Avg
1 2014-12-01     77     NA        NA
2 2015-01-01    886    277 0.3126411
3 2015-02-01    930    383 0.4118280
4 2015-03-01   1167    510 0.4370180
5 2015-04-01   1105    309 0.2796380
6 2015-05-01   1279    319 0.2494136

ggplot(DF_Merge, aes(x=Var1, y=Avg, group = 1)) +
  stat_smooth(aes(x = seq(length(unique(Var1)))),
              se = F, method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 11))
```

[image]

## Bar Graph

```
dfm <- melt(DFtest[ , c("VIN", "First.Launch.Date", "Sale.Date")], id.vars = 1)
dfm$value <- as.Date(cut(dfm$value, breaks = "month"))

ggplot(dfm, aes(x= value, width = 0.4)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), position = "dodge") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "months", labels = date_format("%m-%Y")) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  xlab("Date") + ylab("")
```

[image]

So I managed to make some of the plots which brings me to several questions:

1. How would I combine them into all a single graph using ggplot?
2. Notice how my bar graph has blanks for the first and last month? How do I remove that (precisely, how do I remove 11-2014 and 01-2016 from the x-axis)?
3. In my bar graph, January 2014 had no sales and as a result, the inventory bar takes up a larger space. How do I reduce its size to fit with the rest of the graph?
4. What could I do to change the x-axis from using dates as numbers (i.e.  12-2014) to using month-year in words (i.e. December-2014). I've tried using `as.yearmon` but that doesn't work with the `scale_x_date` portion of my ggplot function.
5. There's also the issue with the average sales rate line which I can safely assume I would be using `geom_hline()` but I am not sure how to approach this.

Comment: to answer the title question, it is impossible to have multiple y-axis in `ggplot` so you won't be able to combine the two graphs.

Comment: So you're saying since the average line uses % and the bars use discrete integers (e.g. 125, 22, 551), its impossible as they are completely different scales?

Comment: Yes, double y-axis are best be avoided as they are easily misused to manipulate conclusions, hence `ggplot2` deliberately doesn't provide the option. I believe it is possible using `googleVis` however.

Comment: Maybe http://rpubs.com/kohske/dual_axis_in_ggplot2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using mtoto's suggestion of utilizing `googleVis`, I took a crack at recreating the graph:

```
# Testing Google Vis
mytest <- DF_Merge

library(zoo)
library(plyr) # to rename columns
library(googleVis)

mytest$Var1 <- as.yearmon(mytest$Var1)
mytest$Var1 <- as.factor(mytest$Var1) # googleVis cannot understand yearmon "class" so change it to factor

# Rename columns to ensure comprehension
mytest <- rename(mytest, c("Var1"="Date", "Freq.x"="Listings", "Freq.y"="Sales", "Avg"="Sales Rate"))

# Prepare for values to be displayed right on the plot
mytest$Listings.annotation <- mytest$Listings
mytest$Sales.annotation <- mytest$Sales
mytest$`Sales Rate.annotation` <- percent(mytest$`Sales Rate`) #Googlevis automatically understands that .annotation is used to display values in the graph

# Create average rate line
mytest$`Sales Rate` <- as.numeric(mytest$`Sales Rate`)
mytest$AvgRate <- (sum(mytest$Sales) / sum(mytest$Listings))
mytest <- rename(mytest, c("AvgRate"="Average Sales Rate"))


# Create the annotation for the average line
mytest$`Average Sales Rate.annotation` <- mytest$`Average Sales Rate`
x = nrow(mytest) - 1
mytest$`Average Sales Rate.annotation`[1:x] = "" # Ensures only the last row in this column has a value
mytest$`Average Sales Rate.annotation` <- as.numeric(mytest$`Average Sales Rate.annotation`, na.rm = TRUE)
mytest$`Average Sales Rate.annotation`[nrow(mytest)] <- percent(mytest$`Average Sales Rate.annotation`[nrow(mytest)]) # Transforms only the last row to a proper percentage!

# Plot the graph
column <- gvisComboChart(mytest, xvar= "Date",
                         yvar=c("Listings", "Listings.annotation", "Sales", "Sales.annotation", "Sales Rate", "Sales Rate.annotation", "Average Sales Rate",
                                "Average Sales Rate.annotation"),
                         options=list(seriesType="bars",
                                      series="[{type: 'bars', targetAxisIndex:0, color:'orange'},
                                      {type: 'bars', targetAxisIndex:0, color:'green'},
                                      {type: 'line', targetAxisIndex:1, color:'red'},
                                      {type: 'line', targetAxisIndex:1, color:'purple', lineDashStyle:[2,2,20,2,20,2]}]",
                                      vAxes="[{format:'decimal', textPosition: 'out', viewWindow:{min:0, max:200}}, 
                                      {format:'percent', textPosition: 'out', viewWindow:{min:0, max:1}}]",
                                      hAxes="[{textPosition: 'out'}]",
                                      legend = "bottom",
                                      curveType="function",
                                      width=1500,
                                      height=800))

plot(column)
```

The variables could have been named better but I was able to get what I was looking for with my final result:

[image]

Comment: For anyone who wants to recreate the `DF_Merge` variable can run this:
`DF_Merge <- structure(list(Var1 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("2014-12-01", "2015-01-01", "2015-02-01", "2015-03-01", "2015-04-01", "2015-05-01"), class = "factor"), Freq.x = c(77, 886, 930, 1167, 1105, 1279), Freq.y = c(NA, 277, 383, 510, 309, 319), Avg = c(NA, 0.3126411, 0.411828, 0.437018, 0.279638, 0.2494136)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))` Also the function `percent()` seems to come from [memisc](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/memisc/index.html) package, so don't forget to load it.